# Getting data from multiple related tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some related tables

USERS

```
+----+--------------------------+------------+
| id | email                    | first_name |
+----+--------------------------+------------+
|  2 | Kovacek.Elisha@gmail.com | Loren      |
|  3 | Cale.Beatty@gmail.com    | Fernando   |
|  4 | dKoss@Brown.com          | Evelyn     |
+----+--------------------------+------------+
```

EVENTS

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Dolores ve |
|  2 | Harum erro |
|  3 | Ratione qu |
+----+------------+
```

EVENT_USER (join)

```
+---------+----------+
| user_id | event_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        3 |
|       1 |       13 |
|       1 |       48 |
+---------+----------+
```

along with other tables related to user ( messages, connections ) etc

I want to get a count of messages, connections and other related data for users of a specific event

SQL I've tried:

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`first_name`, u.`last_name`, 
COUNT(m.`id`) as message_count,
COUNT(a.`id`) as article_count
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `event_user` eu ON u.`id` = eu.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `messages` m ON u.`id` = m.`from`
LEFT JOIN `articles` a ON u.`id` = a.`user_id`
WHERE
eu.`event_id` = 3
GROUP BY u.`id`
```

But the counts are coming out to be same for both columns.

i.e. message_count and article_count are same for all users.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com with some sample data from all the tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is using `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`first_name`, u.`last_name`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`) as message_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.`id`) as article_count
```

If the values are large, then you might want to rewrite the query to aggregate *before* doing the joins.

The reason that you are getting the same values is that `count(<column>)` simply counts the number of non-null values.  So, your query is saying that all users have both messages and articles (if one or the other were missing, the `left join`s would produce `NULL` values).

Comment: This works. Im trying to wrap my head around the concept though.